# Understanding session entropy

Tags: php, session, entropy

In the article https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insufficient_Session-ID_Length
you can read about session guessing attacks.

How long would an attacker need to find a valid/active session?

[image]

```
B is the number of bits of entropy in the session identifier
A is the number of guesses an attacker can try each second
S is the number of valid session identifiers
  that are valid and available to be guessed at any given time
```

Most PHP default settings use md5 hashing (128 bits).
When I use 128 for B, 1000 for A and 500 for S, I get the result of `3,4028236692093846346337460743177e+32` seconds, or roughly `10790283070806014188970529,15499` years.

Seems pretty ok. I have never seen any session on any website having less than 128 bit, (**question:**) or is there something wrong with my assumptions?

Are the default values *safe* ?

Using this now (paranoia mode)

```
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha512');
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 6);
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.entropy_length', 128);
```

Generating sessions ids like:

```
K7ZvnlbRth5JbbJIRIDWdljiKHnP2fRrOVpCMxSbp9rO4OWzynraCon3O-Gfu9beuy2YGHEBpE14uvMzOfVvj3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, brute-force attack is very primitive type of attack.

No one will try to brute-force a hashing algorithm with current performance borders.

1,000 session guesses per second I believe is also far from reality. Any brute-force attack is limited by bandwidth and most firewalls will block such amount of requests per second.

If you are concerned about session security, you need to think about **secure data transmission** between client and server, because most of attacks will try to steal session key instead of trying to brute-force it. [(wiki link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)

Comment: When and where did people use, let's say, 32 bit session id's ?

Comment: My assumption is for sessions with short TTL, for example for a short connection to fetch / refetch some insensetive data.